# Como puedo negar el acceso de cierto usuario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas soy algo nuevo en rails lo que quiero lograr es que el usuario de tipo empleado no pueda iniciar sesion en mi pagina  web,solo el administrador podra iniciar sesion , no abra una vista de empleado en la  web asi que no podra redireccinarse a una vista de empleados este usuario.
Estoy usando la gema devise.

Tengo una tabla usuario con el campo tipo.

user.rb

```
enum tipo: {
admin: 0,
empleado: 1
```

}
Este fue mi intento de solucionar mi problema

application_contoller.rb

```
def user_can_access(resource)
 if current_user
   if resource.admin?
    root_path
 else
   sign_out current_user
   new_user_session_path
 end
end
```

funciona el metodo pero el usuario con el rol empleado inicia sesion pero lo desconecto en mi metodo y lo redirecciono al inicio de sesion cosa que creo que esta mal.

Alguien conoce otra solucion ? si es posible que no sean gemas.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor es que uses la gema [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)
y aqui tienes un pequeño [tutorial](https://www.mintbit.com/blog/authorization-with-cancancan-in-rails)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).